# How do you use regex in php to find a space that has a letter on its left and a number on its right?

Tags: php, regex

How do you do a regex in php that finds a space that has a letter on its left and a number on its right?

I have done many of these over the last day and at best I can find the "letter space number" combo, but I do not know how to find just the space between the letter and number.  I would like to replace this space with a comma.

E.G:

```
The big red Fox 283 brown balls
```

would be converted to:

```
The big red Fox,283 brown balls
```

Thank you in advance for answering this question.  If you provide an explanation with how the answer works it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function to do this:

```
$string = 'The big red Fox 283 brown balls';
preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]) ([0-9])/', '$1,$2', $string);
```

The `[a-zA-Z]` part of the regex matches any letter, and the `[0-9]` matches any digit.  Together, `/[a-zA-Z] [0-9]/` means that we want to match any letter followed by a space, followed by a digit.

The circle brackets denote [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which allows parts of the original string to be "remembered" (in the variables `$1` and `$2`) so that we can include those matched strings in the replacement string.

Comment: I was afraid that it would have to be something like this.  So would this still work for a string like this `"2011.11.1 8:37,Teac Otus,Omber Mining Crystal II 3,Mining Crystal"` where the comma would go between the II and the 3 reading `"2011.11.1,8:37,Teal'c Ostus,Omber Mining Crystal II,3,Mining Crystal"` ?

Comment: @Wes next time please use your real data so you don't have to ask the question twice

Comment: worked like a charm.  I was afraid I would have to match everything before what i needed.  I did not know you could make it localized like this.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this should work if you want to insert a comma between the `II` and the `3`.  But it will not add a comma between `2011.11.1` and `8:37` because in that case, you have numbers on both sides of the space.

Comment: Perfect.  If I could give you another +1 I would.  Regex is very hard for me to understand for some reason.  Ill get it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$str = 'The big red Fox 283 brown balls';
$regex = '/([a-zA-Z])\s(\d)/';
$str = preg_replace( $regex, '$1,$2', $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<?php
$subject = "The big red Fox 283 brown balls";
$pattern = "/ [0-9]/";
$replacement = ",$0";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
?>
```

Output is `The big red Fox, 283 brown balls`

Answer (score 0):

Why does no one like the [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? They are perfect for such a task and you don't have to work with capturing groups.

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z]) (?=[0-9])/i', ',', $string);
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v78f)

I reduced the character class to `[a-z]` and together with the modifier `i` at the end it is also matching the uppercase letters.

Comment: I think lookarounds are advanced constructs which I think most of the regex users are not even aware of. May be that is the reason people don't use them. Also, if you use lookarounds the regex pattern becomes long and the replace expression becomes short and if you use capturing groups, regex pattern becomes short and replace expression is a bit long. Consider `'/([a-z]) (\d)/i', '$1,$2'` vs
`'/(?<=[a-z]) (?=\d)/i', ','`

Answer (score -1):

Use `/\d\s\w/` to match that sequence.
Also if you want to test your regular expressions you can use sites like http://rubular.com/

Comment: This would match a number followed by a space followed by a letter, when i asked for a letter followed by a space followed by a number.  Additionally, the match has to be only the space but the space must be between a letter and a number.

Comment: `\w` matches "word" characters, which includes digits. Yours would match `1 2`, `1 a`, etc.., which is backwards from what the OP wants and also much more as \w includes \d.